# How can I solve $ \lim_{x \to 4^{-}}(4-x)^{(1-\cos(x-4))} $ using small o notation?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to solve this limit using small o notation:
$$ \lim_{x \to 4^{-}}(4-x)^{(1-\cos(x-4))} $$

I tried this:

$$ \lim_{x \to 4^{-}}e^{(1-\cos(x-4))\ln(4-x)} $$
$$ t = x-4 , t \to 0^{-} $$
$$ \lim_{t \to 0^{-}}e^{1-\cos(t)\ln(-t)}  = \lim_{t \to 0^{-}}e^{\frac{t^{2}}2+o(t^{2}) \ln(-t)} $$

But I'm stuck here. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot parentheses, and mixed up $t$ and $x$... so, it should be at the end $$e^{\left(\frac{t^2}{2}+o(t^2)\right)\ln(-t)}$$
or equivalently
$$e^{\left(\frac{t^2}{2}+o(t^2)\right)\ln(t)},$$

when $t\to 0^+$. Notice that when $t\to 0^+$, you have that $\left(\frac{t^2}{2}+o(t^2)\right)\ln(t)\to 0$, and thus,

$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}e^{\left(\frac{t^2}{2}+o(t^2)\right)\ln(t)}=1.$$

So, if you want to use $o$ notation, you have that $$\left(\frac{t^2}{2}+o(t^2)\right)\ln(t)=o(1),$$

when $t\to 0^+$. Using that fact that $e^u=1+o(1)$ when $u\to 0$ gives $$e^{\left(\frac{t^2}{2}+o(t^2)\right)\ln(t)}=e^{o(1)}=1+o(1).$$

Comment: Why when  t→0+ (t^2/2+o(t^2))ln(t)→0?

Comment: because $t^\alpha \ln(t)\to 0$ when $t\to 0^+$ for all $\alpha >0$ @Grinza

Comment: sorry if I bother you, could you explain better the step to obtain o(1)? did you use the properties of small o? If so which ones?